# API Documentation to integrate with Live Channels App

Tags: android, android-tv

I would like to create an app which integrates with the official [Live Channels](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tv&hl=de&gl=US) application from Android TV but I cannot find documentation how to do it. The only thing i found is the deprecated [TV input services API](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif). There are apps on the PlayStore which integrate with the app so it must be possible. Any link to the documentation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Live Channels application is being deprecated and replaced by Live tab, but at the moment there is not much information about how would that affect older devices or will it allow custom applications to add their content to it. So my advice, do not bother integrating this functionality.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As I have already stated in my answer - there is not much documented information on this.